# Radgrid fire RowClick Event via Javascript or Just use EnablePostbackOnRowClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

Worth the discussion

what are the pro's / Con's of firing the RowClick event from a telerik radgrid with following scenario's, they all work btw ;-)

**Scenario 1:**

Radgrid

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="RG_SelectedIndexChanged"
ClientSettings.EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true"
```

Code behind

```
protected void RG_SelectedIndexChanged(){}
```

**Scenario 2:**

Radgrid

```
OnItemCommand="RG_ItemCommand"
ClientSettings.EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true"
```

Code Behind

```
Protected void RG_ItemCommand()
{
 if(e.commandname == "RowClick")
{
}
}
```

**Scenario 3:**

Radgrid

```
OnItemCommand="RG_ItemCommand"
ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnRowClick="RG_RowClick"
```

Javascript

```
function RG_RowClick(sender, eventArgs) {
var index = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
sender.get_masterTableView().fireCommand("RowClick", index);
}
```

Behind

```
Protected void RG_ItemCommand()
{
 if(e.commandname == "RowClick")
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Scenario 1 & 2:

All events in RadGrid fires **ItemCommand** first. Then bubble up that event to a specific event such as **SelectedIndexChanged**, **InsertCommand**, **UpdateCommand**.

Basically, if you want to do something before **SelectedIndexChanged** event is called, you want to perform that task in **ItemCommand** event.

### Scenario 3:

Scenario 3 just calls the server side **ItemCommand** event from client side.

It is basically same as Scenario 2 unless you want to perform any client side tasks even before **ItemCommand** is called at server side. For example, *"Are you sure you want to...?"*

If you do not need client side features, just simply use Scenario 1 or 2 which is much more cleaner and more maintainable.